# How to make IntelliJ redeploy and put all necessary files back?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

**IntelliJ** has local Tomcat Run configuration and it's building project using internal build tool. I deleted all files from `target` directory. Now when I try to run IntelliJ configuration for web application it  results in `404 Not Found` error because IntelliJ did not put back all this files. How to make IntelliJ compile and deploy files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In intellij there is such concept as *Artifact*, it reflects maven's pom artifact. So you can configure your project to produce specific file - it can be zip, war, jar, etc..

Go to `project structure` -> `artifacts`. There you can create or see your existing artifacts.
After you will see that paths are fine, and output layout is ok, you can rebuild artifact:
`Build` -> `Build artifact`.
Then artifact should be created in folder as artifact was configured.

Answer (score 0):

You should list instructions to make your project and deploy it in the application server before launch configuration section and deploy section of your run configuration.